# I need some debug help please

Tags: javascript, debugging

I just started learning JavaScript. I tried to make a simple game to see if I could. But I keep getting errors. I fix one but I get another so can someone please help me debug this? 
I know I am missing something simple.

Right now I am getting:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here is my code:

```
confirm("Are you ready to play 'I CAN GUESS THAT'? A game where Player 2 tries to guess player 1 number?");
//find out names
var player1 = prompt("Player 1 what is your name?","Your name here");
var player2 = prompt("Player 2 what is your name?","Your name here");
//player 1 number 
var p1 =place_holder
while(p1 <1000000) {
var p1 = prompt("Player 2 look away." + " " + player1 + " " + "what is your number?", "Your number under 1,000,000 here");
};
//set up used guess list
var listlow = []
var listhigh = []
var x = 0
var p2 =place_holder
//game 
while( x <11) {
//list used guesses
console.log("Your guess so far");
console.log("Your to low guesses" + listlow);
console.log("Your to high gusses" + highlist);
//player 2 guess
var p2= prompt("Player 2 what is your guess?");
//good guess
var test = p1/p2
    if (test === 1){
        console.log("Congrats" + " " + player2 + "You have guessed" + " " + player1 + "number");
    var x = 30;
//to low
}if (test > 1) {
    console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to low");
    listlow.push(p2);
    x=x++;
//to high
}else if(test <1){
    console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to high");
    listhigh.push(p2);
    x=x++;
//something went wrong
}else if
    console.log("Opps something went wrong");
};
console.log("Thanks for playing")
```

Edit: i changed the else to if else and i am still getting that error

Comment: `if else` is not valid syntax in any language. You want `else if`.

Comment: did you add a `;` at the end of `var x = 30`

Comment: Just did sill a error

Comment: what error (still the same?)

Comment: your code is still not right the `if else(test > 1)` should be `else if(text > 1)` and `if else(test <1)` should be `else if(test <1)` and the last `else if` should be `else`

Comment: now i am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: you need `;` after `var x = 30`

Comment: The last four lines starting with a line `else if` are yet wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your `if else` statements should be `else if` statements and you need a `;` after `var x = 30`

```
confirm("Are you ready to play 'I CAN GUESS THAT'? A game where Player 2   tries to guess player 1 number?");
//find out names
var player1 = prompt("Player 1 what is your name?","Your name here");
var player2 = prompt("Player 2 what is your name?","Your name here");
//player 1 number
var place_holder = 0; 
var p1 =place_holder;
while(p1 > 1000000 || p1 == 0) {
    p1 = prompt("Player 2 look away." + " " + player1 + " " + "what is your number?", "Your number under 1,000,000 here");
    if (p1 != parseInt(p1)){
        p1 = 0;
    }
};
//set up used guess list
var listlow = [];
var listhigh = [];
var x = 0;
var p2 =place_holder;
//game 
while( x <11) {
//list used guesses
console.log("Your guess so far");
console.log("Your to low guesses" + listlow);
console.log("Your to high gusses" + highlist);
//player 2 guess
var p2= prompt("Player 2 what is your guess?");
//good guess
var test = p1/p2;
    if (test === 1){
        console.log("Congrats" + " " + player2 + "You have guessed" + " " + player1 + "number");
        var x = 30;
    //to low
    }else if(test > 1) {
        console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to low");
        listlow.push(p2);
        x=x++;
    //to high
    }else if(test <1){
        console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to high");
        listhigh.push(p2);
        x=x++;
    //something went wrong
    }else{
        console.log("Opps something went wrong");
    }
};
console.log("Thanks for playing")
```

Comment: Changed it still getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Comment: Almost there:  It starts to run now but need to define place_holder

Comment: just add `var place_holder = 0` near the top

Comment: getting stuck in the first loop where p1=5    also thanks for the help

Comment: Well the number is going to be under 1000000 so it will continue. Let me change my code and look at it again.

Comment: i wanted to make sure player one did not do p1=dog

Comment: added if statement to check if it is a number

Comment: Edited it so it should work. Sorry used the java version instead of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change if else to else if:

```
var test = p1/p2;
    if (test === 1){
        console.log("Congrats" + " " + player2 + "You have guessed" + " " + player1 + "number");
        var x = 30;
    //to low
    }else if(test > 1) {
        console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to low");
        listlow.push(p2);
        x=x++;
    //to high
    } else if (test <1){
        console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to high");
        listhigh.push(p2);
        x=x++;
    //something went wrong
    }else{
        console.log("Opps something went wrong");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if else` syntax is incorrect; you should have `else if`:

```
if (test === 1){
    console.log("Congrats" + " " + player2 + "You have guessed" + " " + player1 + "number");
    var x = 30
//to low
} else if(test > 1) {
    console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to low");
    listlow.push(p2);
    x=x++;
//to high
} else if(test <1){
    console.log(player2 + "Sorry your guess is to high");
    listhigh.push(p2);
    x=x++;
//something went wrong
} else{
    console.log("Opps something went wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Else does not need the `()`. Only if statement get the parens.

Comment: Why is this incorrect? Does the else statement need parens?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: This is true, but the OP is clearly trying to create a chain of tests with `else if` logic. A plain `else` clause is already there in the OP and it looks fine.

Comment: OK. Perhaps I rushed.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with your last `else if` statement. There is no if condition to evaluate!

Probably expecting `else if(//some sort of condition)` but you wrote `else if` without the condition.